# JavaScript: Split JSON into several parts

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a json that looks like this:

```
{ "1":{ "alerts":"true","sound":"sound.wav" }, "2":{"alerts":"true","sound":"sound.wav"}}
```

To be separated **in the middle** into two parts:

```
{ "1":{ "alerts":"true","sound":"sound.wav" }}
```

and:

```
{ "2":{"alerts":"true","sound":"sound.wav"}}
```

I tried to do this...

```
var json = '["sss":{"fff":"fff"},"ddd":{"aaa":"aaa"}]';
var jsonArray = JSON.parse(json);
if(jsonArray.length > 1){

}
```

---

**Please help me, Thanks!**

Comment: Take a look at the documentation for the [JSON.stringify()](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_stringify.asp) and [String.split()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) methods.

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. Stack Overflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try using [Object Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Syntax) to split your individual items in the object.

```js
const obj = {
  item_1: {
    "alerts": "true",
    "id": "item_1",
    "sound": "sound.wav"
  },
  item_2: {
    "alerts": "true",
    "id": "item_2",
    "sound": "sound.wav"
  }
};

const {
  item_1,
  item_2
} = obj;

console.log({
  item_1
});
```

Comment: This is missing the property key which is in OP's expected result.

Comment: I need it to look like this: {item_1: {
    "alerts": "true",
    "id": "item_1",
    "sound": "sound.wav"
  }}

Comment: And the other will look like this: {item_2: { "alerts": "true", "id": "item_2", "sound": "sound.wav" }}

Comment: you can then wrap it to an object like `{item_1}`. have updated the code, thanks